# 2D grid repair and smoothing in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project that generates a 2D array of doubles. We then take derivatives of those tables both vertically and horizontally to determine various properties. The problem is, that in some cases, particularly when we join two tables together, we can get a sharp turn (or kink). Any kink in the original table can produce very bad points in the derivatives.

What we'd like to do is to repair the kink in the original table. If we could smooth it out, the derivatives would be fine and everyone would be happy.

Unfortunately, that seems to be pretty tricky. We've tried a couple of things already.

**The Livermore Interpolation Package:** LIP works pretty well, but it isn't designed for this kind of work. I can cut out an entire row or entire column and interpolate over it, but I can't repair specific points. That method also tends to produce bad derivatives in the gap direction, where LIP has no guidance.

**1D splines via the Gnu Scientific Library**: By taking the 2D grid one row or column at a time, I can cut out the bad points and use the GSL 1D spline package to smoothly interpolate over the missing points. This produces good derivatives in the spline's direction, but in the other direction the derivatives come out as complete crap.

So, I'm looking for some library that will allow me to smooth over rough points in 2D to the 2nd derivative. I can designate the bad points if necessary, so the package does not have to automatically detect the bad points (although that might be a nice feature.)

There is a matlab library called "inpaint_nans" that seems like it would do what I want, but I need a C++ library.

Nurbs also seem promising.  Has anyone used them for something like this?  There are quite a few free Nurbs libraries, libNurbs, Nurbs++, and SISL.  Does anyone have a recommendation about which to use?  Does one have this kind of repair functionality?